# Fastly insert 200+ data to the tables with relationship - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

### Table: vacancies

**id**  int unsigned Auto Increment
**code**    varchar(191) NULL
**start_time**  timestamp NULL
**end_time**    timestamp NULL
**business_unit_id**    int unsigned
**job_id**  int unsigned
**on_date** date
**break**   int NULL
**shift_id**    int unsigned
**total_numbers**   int

### Table: vacancy_details

**id**  int unsigned Auto Increment
**vacancy_id**  int unsigned
**day_id**  int unsigned
**shift_id**    int unsigned
**rate_type**   enum('flat_rate','hourly_rate') [hourly_rate]
**start_time**  timestamp NULL
**end_time**    timestamp NULL
**break**   int NULL
**total_hours** decimal(10,2) NULL
**client_rate** decimal(8,2) NULL

### Table: vacancy_staff_rates

**id**  int unsigned Auto Increment
**vacancy_id**  int unsigned
**vacancy_detail_id**   int unsigned NULL
**employment_type_id**  int unsigned
**staff_rate**  decimal(8,2) NULL

```
public function store_multiple($subdomain, Request $request){
    if($request){
        $payloads = $request->data;
        foreach($payloads as $payload){
            $payload = (object) $payload;
            //insertion(3 tables) and all the calculations and logic are doing in this add_vacancy()
            $vacancy = Vacancy::add_vacancy($payload);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the 3 tables. When I'm adding 10 or 20 the insertion is fast but comes 100 or plus it's taking more time. Can anyone suggest a way to do it fatser?

Comment: Try to implement jobs and queues. It will divide your work into smaller chunks.  Ref - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues.

Comment: But what if I need instant validation results for each records? @VivekPawar

Comment: How slow is "too slow"?  Even in the slowest way, I would expect 200 single-row inserts to take no more than 2 seconds.  There are multiple ways to speed that up.  Is the disk HDD or SSD?

Comment: @RickJames not 200 single row insertion, there should be some validations and calculations before inserting each row. Means fetching rates for each day for each vacancy row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

Gather the 200 rows into a separate table (perhaps a `TEMPORARY` table).  Then massage the values as needed while in this table.  Some (all?) of the massaging can be done in bulk; that is, all 200 rows at the same time.  If you need to "normalize" (turn some strings into ids) this is a good time to do that.

Then, as a final step do a single `INSERT INTO real SELECT ... FROM temp` to put them where they belong.